# Cosmaps are not updating

Tags: ros, costmap

So i have this problem where i removed an object from map but i can still see it in rviz
.The circle in the upper left corner is removed in real life but not in rviz

[image]

Comment: at first glance, I see a control named `synchronization`

Comment: i changed it but nothing happened. is that some configuration problem ? something i need to set for sure in local costmap params!!! to be able to detect dynamic obstacles